# How to data bind multiple values to a single TextBlock.Text in WP7?

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, textblock

How can I bind 2 properties to a single TextBlock.Text (eg. first name and last name or current value and max value)?

something like:

```
// IValueConverter
public object Convert( .... )
{
    return string.Format("{0} (max: {1})", currentValue, maxValue);
}
```

The problem is I want TextBlock.Text to be updated when `currentValue` **or** `maxValue` has changed. So how can I listen to changes from 2 or more properties using data binding?

Is there another way than usering `IValueConverter`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silverlight 3 (on which the Windows Phone 7 framework is built) doesn't support MultiBinding, which is what you would use to achieve what you need. However, there is a workaround solution that you can use described in the post [MultiBinding for Sivlerlight 3](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx), which should also work on WP7.

Alternatively, you could extend your view model (or at least the properties that you are exposing) to expose a property that aggregates your values and raises property change notification when either changes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did came to the same conclusion. I hoped there would be another solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with WP7.1 (I know you mentioned WP7), take a look at the [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](http://cimbalino.org/). It offers a [MultiBindingBehavior](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/05/17/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multibindingbehavior/).